# Language item-fallback error when using Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder method

Tags: language-fallback

When trying to use `@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder()` method on a language versioned fallback item, it yields no results.

[image]

I have verified that the context item falls back in Sitecore, and that the `@Html.Sitecore().CurrentItem.IsFallback` is true on fallback items, and pointing to the right item with `@Html.Sitecore().CurrentItem.IsFallback`:

[image: Debug info from running instance]

Has anyone encountered a similar error, and found a solution?

Comment: Have you checked that the current item has renderings added to the `main` placeholder?

Comment: I don't understand the question, what do you mean `When trying to use @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder() method on a language versioned fallback item`? Fields on Placeholder items are Shared and the Placeholder is not used on an item, it is used on a rendering.

Comment: @RichardSeal : Yes, because when I view the item in the default site language (at which it has an existing version), it gives me a correctly rendered page, including the renderings to the main placeholder.

Comment: @jammykam I'll post a screenshot of the markup when I get to work tomorrow. But what I mean is that when i run the page, where the @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder() calls reside in a .cshtml file, I get a correctly rendered page on a language versioned item, but if I try to view a fallback item (which has no language version of its own), then it fails and the Placeholder() method returns are empty

Comment: `<div>
   @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("main")
   @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("footer")
</div>`

Comment: This works as expected on our side. I would raise a Sitecore ticket for that.

Comment: @JesperHoff I was actually able to reproduce this when I designed the presentation details of my default language on the Final Layout. Are you sure the renderings are added to the Shared Layout ?

Comment: @JesperHoff Which version of Sitecore 8.1 are you using?

Comment: Any conclusion to this, or should we proceed to close this Q?

Comment: @MarkCassidy close it

Comment: Closed per OP request. Inconclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are describing is expected if your presentation version-specific. Support for [versioned Presentation Details](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/versioned_layouts/versioned_layouts) is a native feature of Sitecore 8, and you can control the versioned (final) or the shared presentation [when editing 
the presentation details](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/versioned_layouts/use_versioned_layouts) of your item.

[image]

In the screenshot above, note that there is a *Shared Layout* and a *Final Layout* tab in the Layout Details (Presentation Details) dialog. The *Shared Layout* tab corresponds to the presentation that is "shared" and should display regardless of the language version. In contrast, the *Final Layout* tab corresponds to the presentation that is "versioned" and should display only when the item is rendered in the context language. This means that presentation set in the *Final Layout* tab is specific to the language version of the item you are editing. If you want the same presentation settings to apply to all language versions of the item, make sure to set up your presentation in the *Shared Layout* tab.